# Show files that are git ignored in sublime sidebar

Tags: ruby, git, sublimetext, gitignore, tmp

I'm trying to get the tmp file that is git ignored, to display in my sublime sidebar so that i can look at the contents. I have tried everything that I found, including going into preferences => settings and deleting 'tmp' from the 'folder_exclude_patterns' in the user settings but it is still not appearing. I still want the file to be git ignored though.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear; you're saying you want a temp file to appear but that you modified the setting for excluding folders. If the file you want to show in a folder that's being excluded from the side bar?